# How to change pose without deforming my mesh?

Tags: mesh, armature, bones, pose-mode

Im not sure if its possible but there are cases where changing pose (by moving/pulling bones) modify the mesh very uglily.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

How can I prevent it? The place where legs connect is character body, and its very weirdly deformed. Knees deform very well, but body doesnt.

Any help appreciated really.

This is probably caused because the bones are too closer to each other, but thats how I planned these legs to be.

Is it possible without changing plans?

EDIT:my blend file:
[image]

another screen of what im trying to avoid without success:
[image]

Comment: Please attach your .blend by uploading it with the official uploader

Comment: @WhatAMesh i looked in google and generally for official uploader but couldnt find so i used blend exchange hope thats fine.

Comment: Well thats the official one I meant, sorry I should clip the link to my bookmarks and copy paste it

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a lot about the *Skin* modifier but it looks like the parentage was not good. If you apply the *Skin* modifier, then put your armature in *Pose* mode, then put your mesh in *Weight Paint* mode, you can see that the weight painting is not good, the legs control the hip, when they are not supposed to. Now you can correct with the brush.

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for your post. I used weight brush and it changed position of my mesh parts. it doesnt appear red anymore, but its also not in the position i wanted it to be. i only could apply weight paint after applying armature and skin, and somehow i cant move the body anymore via moving bones in pose mode

Comment: don't apply the Armature modifier, only apply the Skin modifier, because I'm not sure you can improve your rigging without applying the Skin modifier. Applying it will just give you a classic mesh.

Comment: even after I apply skin modifier and weight paint it, armature seems to disconnect (when i move bones it doesnt move mesh) PS not sure if i was clear in thread but I wanted to make simple walking and moving legs deforms body as you see

Comment: try to reparent it With Automatic Weight

Comment: that doesnt do anything

Comment: you see on my screenshot that it works, so you must do something wrong somewhere